# A Board of Words

Tags: word, word-property

> bathe halt the
> onion onto aim
> trend mean ate

What three-letter word am I?

Hint:

> anagram

Major hint:

> These are anagrams of words.

> The alphabet

Comment: Is the second spoiler tag also a hint?

Comment: @riskymysteries yes